# Responsive jQuery UI with resizable / draggable elements

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I am attempting to build a responsive interface using jQuery UI, that allows for movable and resizable elements, which will stay in proportion even if the screen is resized.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/NSLmQ/3/

I am using the UI callbacks for `dragStop` and `resizeStop` to convert the pixel position values into percentage values, after the user has completed their resize or drag.

```
function resizeStop(event, ui){
    convert_to_percentage($(this));
}

function dragStop(event, ui){
    convert_to_percentage($(this));
}

function convert_to_percentage(el){
    var parent = el.parent();
    el.css({
        left:parseInt(el.css('left'))/parent.width()*100+"%",
        top: parseInt(el.css('top'))/parent.height()*100+"%",
        width: el.width()/parent.width()*100+"%",
        height: el.height()/parent.height()*100+"%"
    });
}
```

This works perfectly fine if the parent container has an explicit height and width — jQuery UI converts the percentages back to pixels before subsequent resize or drags, and my callbacks return them to percentage *after* the finished resize or drag. All hunky-dory.

The problem occurs **during resize** when the resizable element's parent is set to height:auto (in the linked Fiddle, I am using a child image to give the containing parent a height)

When I attempt to resize the UI element, jQuery UI will improperly convert the percentage of the top and left into pixels, and the element will jump in position.

This problem seems to be Chrome-specific. Firefox exhibits occasional mini-jumps in position, but they seem to be a matter of slight rounding differences. In Chrome, the position shifting is dramatic.

While setting an explicit height on the parent container solves the UI problem, it doesn't allow for a responsive solution.

Any ideas?

===========================================

### Late Update

@peteykun's answer below solved my fundamental problem, but there was one offshoot problem that I thought it might be worth addressing.

Chrome uses sub-pixels when calculating 'auto' sizing, so that getting the height with jQuery through `.height()` returns an inexact, rounded answer (and causes a visual jiggle during the conversion between pixels and percentage, and vice-versa).

Therefore, using the Vanilla JS `.getBoundingClientRect().height` instead of `.height()` returns a sub-pixel result for a jiggleless solution.

```
function setContainerSize(el) {
    var parent = $(el.target).parent().parent();
    parent.css('height',  parent[0].getBoundingClientRect().height+'px');
}
```

Thanks again for your help, @peteykun

Comment: I m unsure of why you are converting to percentages when using position:absolute. seems self-defeating.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about setting the container's `height` explicitly before the resize takes place?

Ideally, this should have been doable with the `start` option for `.resizable{}`, but I tried it out myself, and it did not help. Instead, by binding a `.mouseover()` to the handle, the desired effect seems to be achieved:

```
$('.box')
.resizable({containment: 'parent', handles: "se", create: setContainerResizer, stop:resizeStop})

function setContainerResizer(event, ui) {
    console.log($(this)[0]);
    $($(this)[0]).children('.ui-resizable-handle').mouseover(setContainerSize);
}

function setContainerSize(el) {
    var parent = $(el.target).parent().parent();
    parent.css('height', parent.height() + "px");
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/w2Jje/4/

---

**Update:** <del>In order to retain responsiveness, you can make the height `auto` once again after the resize is complete.</del> Check the update below.

```
function convert_to_percentage(el){
    var parent = el.parent();

    el.css({
        left:parseInt(el.css('left'))/parent.width()*100+"%",
        top: parseInt(el.css('top'))/parent.height()*100+"%",
        width: el.width()/parent.width()*100+"%",
        height: el.height()/parent.height()*100+"%"
    });

    parent.css('height', 'auto'); // Set it back to auto
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/w2Jje/5/

---

**Update #2:** To get around the case where the mouse never leaves the handle before a second resize, let's reset the height on mouseout instead:

```
function setContainerResizer(event, ui) {
    console.log($(this)[0]);
    $($(this)[0]).children('.ui-resizable-handle').mouseover(setContainerSize);
    $($(this)[0]).children('.ui-resizable-handle').mouseout(resetContainerSize);
}

function resetContainerSize(el) {
    parent.css('height', 'auto');
}
```

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/w2Jje/6/

Comment: I haven't had a chance to test this yet, but it seems the most likely to fulfill the requirement.

It does feel a bit like it is treating the symptom, rather than the cause, but perhaps with this particular bug, it is the only option.

I'll give it a test shortly. Thanks.

Comment: On first look, I think I will need to put the conversion back to 'auto' on the mouseout, otherwise if you resize the element twice in a row (without moving your mouse away) the jumping occurs. I will see how it goes.

Comment: Fantastic! I've got it working locally in my larger implementation. Nice job.

Comment: @peteykun I have a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52880510/constantly-move-resizable-draggable-image-on-the-video-when-the-browser-is-resiz?noredirect=1#comment92674974_52880510). I am wondering if you can give me some pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add, the fiddle, and code from the question worked almost perfectly for me, you have to make sure you take into account any padding though when resetting width/height.

```
el.css({
    ...
    width: (el.width()+LEFT_PADDING+RIGHT_PADDING)/parent.width()*100+"%",
    height: (el.height()+TOP_PADDING+BOTTOM_PADDING)/parent.height()*100+"%"
});
```